# While Do Statement with blank/empty grep return?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, if-statement

This is the code for my foobar.sh:

```
!#/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]
do
    pid=`ps -ef | grep "mylittleprogram" | grep -v grep | awk ' {print $2}'`
    echo $pid
    if [ "$pid"="" ]
    then
            echo "Process has ended lets get this show on the road..."
            exit
    else
            echo "Process has not ended yet"
    fi
    sleep 6
done
```

I'm basically running a infinate loop which will execute command X once a monitored process has ended but I end up getting the following message as my script loops:

```
./foobar.sh: line 7: [: missing `]'
Process has not ended yet
```

Is there a way of making the script accept that zero feed back will trigger my 'Then' statement and execute command X since it is not liking the current method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of

```
if [ "$pid"="" ]
```

please try

```
if [ "$pid" = "" ]
```

The whitespace is around `=` is important.

You can also try

```
if [ -z "$pid" ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd do

```
while pgrep -fl "mylittleprogram"; do sleep 6; done
exit # process has ended
```

<sup>(pgrep is in package `psmisc` IIRC)</sup>

I've just tested it. You could redirect the output of `pgrep` to `/dev/null` if you wanted the waiting to be silent. Add some more spice to make things uninterruptible:

```
{
     trap "" INT
     while pgrep -fl "mylittleprogram" >/dev/null
     do 
         sleep 6
     done
     true
} && exit
```

Answer (score 2):

The zero test is `if [ -z "$pid" ]`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the nebulous matching provided by:

```
pid=`ps -ef | grep "mylittleprogram" | grep -v grep | awk ' {print $2}'`
```

...and the archaic backtick syntax, consider this which matches the process basename exactly and produces an output format of your choice (here, the process pid if it exists):

```
pid=$(ps -C mylittleprogram -opid=)
```

Then, as noted, simply test for an empty value:

```
[ -z "${pid" ] && echo "no process" || echo "I live as $pid"
```

The equal sign following the output element name suppresses the heading that you would normally get.  Manpages are your friend.